# Suggestion for "Hint-Only" Tag

Tags: support, tagging, hint

For people who only want guidance in understanding how to approach the problem, as opposed to seeing a fully fleshed out solution.

Would this tag be useful?

Am new to this site, so don't want to create this tag especially if people think that it won't be used. I don't really use tags as yet, so don't understand how others would view it.

Comment: I often see statements of the kind "Looking for a hint, not a full solution" in the body of a question. This is probably more effective than a tag would be. Not everyone looks at the tags as they read a question.

Comment: Meta-tags and dependent tags are generally [discouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/). (But the MSE community decided to [keep a few of them](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/the-meta-tags), anyway.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for that link. I don't understand the discouraged link though, could you explain why you linked to that post?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Tags are for consolidating questions together. There are a few basic ways they get used:

- As ways to search for questions on a particular topic.
- To add to favorite tags.
- To add to ignored tags.
- To hand out tag badges. (This lets the community get a sense for what kind of questions particular users are good at answering.)

Having a hint-only tag serves none of these purposes, so I don't think it would be useful.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation.

Comment: Hmm. In principle I agree. However, the same objections exist against other meta-tags (see the list in Martin Sleziak's link in the comments to the question). Also, it is hard to see that anyone would add a meta-tag to her/his list of personal favorites or search for more questions using such a tag as a buzzword :-). The thought of somebody earning a tag badge on "hints only" does strike me as strange. I guess we would mostly chuckle at such a badge of merit.

Comment: I'd love a [hints-only] badge.  So esoteric.